# Access: How to retrieve a certain field from a table and return it?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subtotal

#### Background

I am currently working on a simple **access database** for a small bookstore. The business sells books as well as other items.
See following ER-diagram [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB1SU.png)

#### Problem

My problem starts in the table `Transaction`. I would like to **create a simple form** where a *subtotal* is calculated as *quantity* purchased multiplied by the *price* (both of a certain item). 
However the `Price` field is either in the `BookInfo`, `FoodAndBev`, or `ApparelAndSupplies` table.

#### Question

How can I traverse the `Transaction` table to `Items` and to one of the tables I listed depending on the *StockNum* in `Transaction`?

For example, a customer buys an item with *StockNum* `BK001`. I would like to retrieve the *Price* corresponding to `BK001` in the *BookInfo* table and return to *Transaction* to be used for calculating the subtotal.

The field `StockNum` exists in tables `BookInfo`, `FoodAndBev`, and `ApparelAndSupplies`.

Sample Data: [BookInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ypZ.png), [Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bsS9.png), [Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeJYl.png)

Ideal Output: Transaction 1: A customer buys 2 copies of a book with *StockNum* 'BK001' (disregard what I already have in the screenshot). The *Price* of 'BK001' is $119.99 which I would need to retrieve from *BookInfo* (my problem is I want to make sure it goes to BookInfo not the other two tables which have *StockNum* also), so the subtotal would then be calculated and would show $239.98. For now, I've been doing this manually. I want to be able to do this with different *StockNum* such as those that start with AS for Apparel and Supplies and FB for food and beverage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried, can you provide a [example] (e.g. SQL).

Comment: Did you consider using [LEFT JOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Join-tables-and-queries-3F5838BD-24A0-4832-9BC1-07061A1478F6) tables based `ON` equal _StockNum_ to lookup _Price_ in one of the product-detail-tables ?

Comment: Hi.  LucidChart says I'm required to login to see the diagram, which I'd prefer not to do.  Can you take a screenshot and post that?

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would be very helpful.

Comment: Having multiple pricing tables really complicates. Can use DLookup() or can include all in form RecordSource and use conditional expression in textbox to retrieve correct price.

Answer (score 0):

Left-Joining all tables and using Case-When-Expression (which is function `switch` in Access) for different price multiplication:

```sql
SELECT t.StockNum, t.NumOrdered, 
switch(
  Left(t.StockNum,2) = 'BK' , (t.NumOrdered * b.Price),
  Left(t.StockNum,2) = 'AS' , (t.NumOrdered * a.Price),
  Left(t.StockNum,2) = 'FB' , (t.NumOrdered * f.Price),
) AS subtotal
FROM Transaction t
LEFT JOIN BookInfo b ON b.StockNum = t.SockNum
LEFT JOIN ApparelAndSupplies a ON a.StockNum = t.SockNum
LEFT JOIN FoodAndBev f ON f.StockNum = t.SockNum
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'b.StockNum = t. StockNum 
LEFT JOIN ApparelAndSupplies a ON a.StockNum = t.StockNum 
LEFT JOIN FoodAndBev f ON f.StockNum = t.StockNum

I have table bridging the Transaction table and the three tables called Items, could that be causing a problem? Thank you for the help!